# Ember app won't load data from has_many relationships using ActiveModelAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This app works fine when the store is FixtureAdapter, but will not load has_many relationships when the store is ActiveModelAdapter.

The Route is like this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.find('post', 1 )
  }
});
```

The models are like this:

```
App.Post =  DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comments', {embedded: 'always'})
});

App.Comment =  DS.Model.extend({
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  post: DS.belongsTo('post')
});
```

The handlebars template calls for:

```
{{name}}
{{#each comments}}
   {{text}}
{{/each}}
```

The name appears, the comments do not. 
In the ember developer console, the comments are not getting loaded at all.

The server seems to be serving the serialized content correctly (as far as I can tell). It looks like this:

```
{"post":{"id":1,"name":"Title","description":"Lorem Ipsum","comments":[{"id":1, "text": "commentary here"}]}}
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working and how I could fix it? I've been struggling with this for hours now and cannot figure out why it's not working. Thanks very much for any insight you can provide.

I'm using this as part of a Rails project, and these are the relevant gems:

```
gem 'ember-rails'
gem 'ember-source', '1.3.0'
gem 'ember-data-source', '~> 1.0.0.beta.6'
gem "active_model_serializers"
```

Comment: which adapter are you using?  Embedded is only implemented for the active model adapter, https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: @kingpin2k I'm using adapter: DS.ActiveModelAdapter

Comment: And which version of ED are you using?

Comment: @kingpin2k 1.0.0.beta.4  (I'm using in a Rails app, so I loaded like this: gem 'ember-data-source', '~> 1.0.0.beta.4'  )

Comment: I just updated to the latest, 1.0.0.beta.6, but that did not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a custom adapter for each over-riden model and mixin the Embedded Records Mixin:

```
App.PostSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
        comments: {embedded: 'always'}
    }
});
```

Please see the comments in the Ember-Data source code for more info.

Comment: Thanks @buuda this helps. Would you mind linking to the comments your referencing in the source code?

Comment: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html and https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.6/packages/activemodel-adapter/lib/system/active_model_serializer.js